# Vscode view container icon not showing

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a vscode extension that contributes a **view container**. The view container is working and I can interact with it, however, it **doesn't show the icon**.

I already changed my custom icon to an icon provided with one of the vscode extension samples and it still doesn't show, so it's **not a problem with the svg file**. Also I looked at some published extensions as examples and can't really see anything different then what I did.

Here are the relevant parts of my `package.json`:

```
"viewsContainers": {
    "activitybar": [
        {
            "id": "alg-organizer",
            "title": "alg",
            "icon": "./resources/dark/logo.svg"
        }
    ]
},
"views": {
    "alg-organizer": [
        {
            "id": "todos",
            "name": "TODO"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is how the view is displayed:

[image]

I expect the icon to be shown, so I'm sure missing something but can't quite figure out what.

Comment: It turns out the root folder becomes the typescript output directory, so I had to copy the resources there.

Comment: It's not the wrong path, is it?